# ¿Cómo actualizar *ngFor cuando se modifica la lista a la que apunta?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-directivas

Actualmente estoy mostrando una lista proveniente de bd usando *ngFor. He agregado un campo para filtrar por nombre, y al hacerlo se actualiza el array sólo con los items que contienen ese string. Sin embargo, la lista sigue sin actualizarse.

El código de la vista:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of screenService.itemList" class="list-item" id="list-item-{{item.Key}}">
<div *ngIf="item.Status.Color" class="status-color {{item.Status.Description}}"></div>
<div class="item-content" (click)="showItemInfo(item.Key)">
    <h1 class="list-item-title">{{item.Name}}</h1>
    <div class="list-item-info">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let property of screenService.properties">
                    {{item[property]}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item-buttons" *ngIf="screenService.screenToDisplay === 'list'">
    <button (click)="screenService.deleteItem(item.Key)" class="button-white" style="float: right">Delete</button>
    <button (click)="showEditScreen(item.Key)" class="button-white" style="float: right">Edit</button>
</div>
```

Como se ve, el *ngFor está apuntando a un array llamado itemList. Cuando hago el filtro ese array se vuelve a rellenar únicamente con los items que contienen ese texto. ¿Pero por qué no se actualiza la vista?

Imagen de la vista:
[image]

Función para obtener los datos filtrados y actualizar la variable:

```
getItemFiltered(url){
    this.http.get(url)
    .pipe(map((data : Response) =>{
        return data.json() as Item[];
    })).toPromise().then(x => {
        this.itemList = x;
    })
}
```

Valor de itemList tras el filtro:
[image]

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Me falta código para entender lo que pasa: ¿cómo haces el filtro? ¿Usas splice para sacar elementos?

Comment: Buenas Pablo, lo que hago es volver a hacer la llamada a db agregándole where statusName.contains(filtro). Agrego la funcion en la pregunta, para mas info.

Comment: ¿Guardas los datos en el service? El componente nunca sabrá si esos datos han cambiado

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema que tienes es el siguiente:

1. Tu componente pide los datos al servicio.
2. El servicio no le da los datos al componente, sino que los busca y los guarda en un atributo propio (`itemList`).
3. El componente muestra los datos que hay en `this.screenService.itemList`.

Puesto que itemList no es un atributo del componente, Angular no detecta el cambio y no actualiza la vista.

La forma correcta de hacerlo sería la siguiente:

En el servicio devolvemos el observable:

```
getItemFiltered(url){
    this.http.get(url)
    .pipe(map((data : Response) =>{
        return data.json() as Item[];
    }));
}
```

**Nota:** Si usas angular 5 o posterior, el servicio debería usar `HttpClient` y no `Http`, con lo que el método sería tan simple como:

```
getItemFiltered(url){
    this.http.get<Item[]>(url);
}
```

En el componente tendrías algo como:

```
getItemFiltered(filter:string) {
  //generar la url, aunque realmente eso debería hacerlo también el service
  this.screenService.getItemFiltered(url)
    .subscribe(list => this.itemList=list);
}
```

De este modo, tu bucle quedaría como:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemList" class="list-item" id="list-item-{{item.Key}}">
```

Y angular sabría cuando actualizar

Comment: Gracias Pablo, lo he estado probando viendo tu anterior comentario. El problema actual es que el filtro es un componente distinto al de la lista. Y al importar éste en el componente de filtro para actualizar la variable me da un StaticInjectorError(AppModule)

Comment: No acabo de entender lo que comentas... necesitaría ver el código

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo he tenido ese problema y lo he resuelto usando las capacidadades de Angular usando un **custom pipe** para realizar el filtrado de la lista una vez que el observable esta resuelto. 
Codigo:

```
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let property of screenService.properties | filtrarNombre: variableQueContieneElValorAFiltrar">
                {{item[property]}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Nota: Seria interesante si revisa el proceso de rendering porque no me parece que como lo tiene implementado es la forma optima.

Este html codigo require otros elementos crear ***filtro-por-nombre.pipe.ts***:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filtrarNombre',
    pure: false
})

export class FiltroPorNombre implements PipeTransform {
    transform(elementos: any[], nombre: string): any {
        if (!elementos|| !nombre) {
            return elementos;
        }

        return elementos.filter(elemento => elementos.Name.indexOf(nombre) !== -1);
    }
}
```

Ya casi terminamos, ahora en el modulo que usa este filtro agregar algo como esto:

```
import { FiltroPorNombre } from './pipes/filtro-por-nombre.pipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ..
    ],
    declarations: [
        FiltroPorNombre ,
    ],
    providers: [
        ..
    ],
    bootstrap: [MiComponente]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Esto tipo de filtro puede ser tan complicado como la logica requiera, es muy util y puede ser reutilizado.

Espero sea util la respuesta.